# Connection refusing in android post data sending

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post

I tried sending POST data(s) into a local PHP server on my own network, and tried a test code. But the connection is refusing for some reason (even though my network's okay) and i can not send post data to my server (e.g: http://192.168.1.103/bot/post.php)
Can anyone suggest me what's causing the error here? Thanks in advance!

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "Main2Activity.java";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    new PostDataAsyncTask().execute();
}

public class PostDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            postData();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String lenghtOfFile) {
    }
}

// POST the datas
    private void postData() {
    try {
        String postReceiverUrl = "http://192.168.1.103/bot/post.php";
        Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("abcd", "1234"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("asif", "5678"));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // execute
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (resEntity != null) {
            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
            Log.v(TAG, "Response: " + responseStr);
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }}
```

And in the stacktrace:

```
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.103 refused
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:195)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:366)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:596)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:517)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:495)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at pericolosopyat.shoppingbot.Main2Activity.postData(Main2Activity.java:73)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at pericolosopyat.shoppingbot.Main2Activity.access$000(Main2Activity.java:23)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at pericolosopyat.shoppingbot.Main2Activity$PostDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(Main2Activity.java:43)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at pericolosopyat.shoppingbot.Main2Activity$PostDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(Main2Activity.java:35)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:316)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:255)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Permission denied
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:192)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.593 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:    ... 16 more
2019-06-29 20:16:26.594 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
2019-06-29 20:16:26.594 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:460)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.594 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:590)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.594 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:124)
2019-06-29 20:16:26.594 29115-29163/pericolosopyat.shoppingbot W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says in your stack-trace `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied` which means you've not added the appropriate permission to your manifest, simply add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your root `AndroidManifest.xml` file before the application tag.

Comment: Try upvoting and accepting the answer with the right information! and for your php problem, post it as another appropriate question with your code.

Comment: @Asif-UlIslamAkash, glad to help. Happy coding :)